# Remove border from Bootstrap accordion

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, border, accordion

I've been stuck on this (apparently easy) thing that I can't manage to solve.
I'm using Bootstrap 3.2.0 and I'm not able to remove the line between the accordion panel title and the panel body while every other border and shadow is gone. I've already tried every suggestion that was possibly given before posting but got no luck. This is the HTML code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <p class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">PROJECTS</a>
        </p>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#napoli" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">NAPOLI</a></li>
            <li><a href="#portraits" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">PORTRAITS</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
   </ul>
</div>
```

And here is the relevant CSS so far...

```
.panel-group{
    margin:0;
}

.panel{
    border:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}

.panel-heading{
    padding:0;
}
```

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rgi0nkvec4qtoyq/file.jpg?dl=0) is how it look like:

Comment: I am on my phone but I see a bad close tag  after the word Napoli </

Comment: I don't think the shadow is Bootstrap boilerplate for the accordion, meaning I think you are picking it up from somewhere else possibly.  When you inspect the element, what element has the shadow?

Comment: The css is missing Panel Title. Add it and set border to 0

Comment: @RodrigoSantiaborg I had tried already to set the .panel-title borders to 0 but it doesn't work...

Comment: This isnt a solution but here is a fiddle to help out.

http://jsfiddle.net/plushyObject/tpd0gzk8/

Comment: @plushyObject when I inspect the element the shadow seems to belong either to the bottom of  `panel-heading`or `panel-title`or to the top of `panel-collapse`
In your fiddle there is still the shadow when you click on the header.. can you see it?

Comment: Here you go man http://jsfiddle.net/plushyObject/tpd0gzk8/1/

Comment: And this one works too... :) thanks @plushyObject!

Comment: Again, using !important is considered terrible practice and makes you look like a noob.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DON'T USE !IMPORTANT.

This works:

```
.panel, .panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body{
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: Can also add "box-shadow: none;" to remove what looks like a bottom border

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It works for me to remove the default blue border that appears when clicking on the accordion heading.

```css
:focus {
  outline: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

.panel-body {border-top: 0 !important;}

This takes care of the question, but perhaps it would be better to add a custom class, or inline style, that only removed the border where needed.

Comment: Don't override with !important.  That is bad. My solution is better dude.

Comment: using !important makes it look like you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @plushyObject why then is it available to use in the language?

Comment: If you're using your CSS selectors effectively, you typically won't need to use !important.  I often see people using !important when there is a specificity issue in regards to the styles' cascading, meaning that they're class they have created isn't as specific on a DOM element as another within the CSS, which is why you have a crazy selector like the answer that was selected.

It exists in the language as a quick fix to poorly written CSS.  Sorry if that hurts your feelings.

Comment: !important is just fine to use.  Ignore that rant